# The mainstream media are _____ in/about reporting gossips of celebrities

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I want to fill in the blank of the following sentence with an adjective with a meaning similar to "interested/fascinated/passionate..." but I hope the word sounds negative or ironic:

> The mainstream media are _____ in/about reporting gossips of celebrities and politicians.

Also, it would be great if you can change the structure of the whole sentence to make it idiomatic, if necessary. Thanks!

I also want a literal word. I have thought about "crazy", but I think it is too colloquial.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the best word for that spot would be **obsessive**, as interested sounds more passive than I would like, fascinated sounds like the positive version of obsessive, and passionate also implies something positive, as you are passionate about a hobby.

The [definition of obsessive from Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=fascinated+meaning&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS796US796&oq=fascinated+meaning&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.4239j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is "*a person who is affected by an obsession*", and the [definition of obsession from Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS796US796&ei=VRlzW5n4AcPujwSZrYSADQ&q=obsession&oq=obsession&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.31764.31826.0.31951.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.30JyKVJ2HDo) is "*an idea or thought that continually preoccupies or intrudes on a person's mind*".

Obsession of something is usually looked down upon in society, as an obsession with a particular person is seen as creepy, hence why I decided to use this word.  Going back to my hobby example, people normally say they are passionate about something, like guitar, but never obsessive.  If I was to say "*I am obsessive about playing guitar"*, I would likely get a lot of concerned stares.

The sentence would be essentially saying "***The media cannot report on anything except for people who can only talk about the personal lives of celebrities and politicians***".

---

Your final sentence would therefore be:

> The mainstream media are **obsessed** with reporting the gossip about celebrities and politicians.

Comment: "Gossips" means "people who gossip", not "topics of gossip".

Comment: Your use of *gossips* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Doesn't "are obsessed with" work better here?

Comment: My bad, looks like I missed the "s" in the question.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, obsessive is fine. But: about reporting gossip about or on A and B, needs correcting. I don't think the OP meant gossip of celebrities here....

Comment: Try "the mainstream media **are obsessed with** ..."

Answer (score 2):

are insistent in reporting gossip about celebrities and politicians.

are bent on reporting etc.

are focused on reporting etc.

are unwavering in reporting on x.

gossip does not take an s here. It refers to the activity not people.

Comment: Thanks, but see https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/gossips

Comment: @TiWen The plural doesn't apply here. It's being used as a mass noun. It's not talking about two *people* who are gossips, or a particular person who gossips. It's talking about the phenomenon itself. You're also actually missing an article in your sentence. Like *the weather* it's just *the gossip*. Alternatively, you could use the gerund: *the gossiping*.

Comment: @TiWen You are mistaking the noun referring to the person for the noun referring to the activity.  Your sentence is wrong. Reporting gossip [the activity, no s] about celebrities; reporting celebrity gossip but not: reporting gossips ***of*** celebrities.

Comment: I think _bent on_ is an especially good suggestion in this context. One could use _hell-bent on_ if wanting to make it even more negative.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with

> **to be hung up on sth** ​
>
> to be **extremely interested in** or worried by a particular subject **and spend an unreasonably large amount of time thinking about it**
>
> - the mainstream media **are hung up on** reporting celebrity and political gossip.
>
> In my mind that sounds sarcastic; it invokes the image of desperate journalists doing all the weird stuff to get the best stories and headlines.

My second guess is

> **to be obsessed with sth**
>
> **unable to stop thinking about something**; **too interested** in or worried about something:
>
> - the mainstream media **are obsessed with** <strike>reporting</strike> celebrity and political gossip.
>
> It feels similar to the previous sentence in that journalists are acting irrational etc but I'd say this choice to be obsessed with sth is less snide than to be hung up on sth.

My another guess is

> **to live and breathe sth**
>
> when a person lives and breathes something, it is **extremely important to them**:
>
> - the mainstream media **live and breathe** <strike>reporting</strike> celebrity and political gossip.
>
> This expression sounds almost in favour of the mainstream media compared to the previous two options, it's like gossips and scandals are these people's true passion, which makes this one humorous and sarcastic

~All definitons from CD

---

Grammar fixes as suggested by **@ColleenV** and **@Andrew**

The mainstream media are ___ in/about reporting <strike>gossips of celebrities and politicians</strike> **celebrity and political gossip**

Comment: I agree with all of these verbs, but I still don't like the plural *gossips*.  Gossip is usually an uncountable noun, so the singular should suffice.  Also note that the more common preposition seems to be  "gossip **about**", although "gossip **of**" is fine too.

Comment: You're right, I figured I will just suggest the best expressions to avoid posting a messy answer

Comment: @Andrew Also, “celebrity and political gossip”.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use ***[fixated](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fixation)***:

> fixated, adj.
>   def 1: so interested in someone or something that you do not pay attention to anything else
>   <sub>*definition from [macmillandictionary.com](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fixated)*</sub>
>
> fixate, v.
>   def 3: (*Psychoanalysis*) to develop a fixation; suffer an arrest in one's emotional or sexual development.
>
> Fixation, n.
>   def 5: a preoccupation with one subject, issue, etc.; obsession
>   <sub>*definitions from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fixation)*</sub>

Since this is referring to a psychological disorder, it is definitely negative in tone.

Normally *fixate* takes *on* as its preposition, so your example would be

> The mainstream media are fixated on reporting gossip about politicians and celebrities.